# What is a Blob Vault?

Tags: ripple

The [Blob Vault](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/Blob-Vault) is a part of the Ripple project.
What is it?

The project should get a reamdme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "blob vault" is a very simple encrypted storage system used to store Ripple wallets. Your Ripple wallet stores your annotations, named accounts, and so on. You can create a new wallet with the same secret and get your funds back, so losing your wallet does *not* mean losing your funds.

The [guts](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/Blob-Vault/blob/master/server.js) consist entirely of about 100 lines of Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Not much information to get here https://ripple.com/wiki/Blobvault nor on the github page